# How to Set Push notification using our own App server in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have created app that sends push notification when honework upload to the server. So please can somebody tell me how to send push notification in react native for both androud and ios?

Comment: You can start by reading here https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup. You have a long way to go. basically android push is much easier to achieve but apple asks a lot of stuff before gives you push certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use push notification packages like [Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) or [OneSignal](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal). they have defined API in their documentation and you can send push notification from your server to both android and ios devices easily.